# Future perfect continuous tense of be verb

Tags: tenses, future

The future perfect continuous tense of 'be' verb is a possibility?

1

> I will have been being in the cinema industry for 3 months by this Christmas.

Is this type of sentence construction used in the context?

2
Future continuous tense of be verb, such as

> We will have be being positive towards our attitude throughout.

Is this type of sentence used?
Why this structure is not available so often?

Answer (score 1):

I think the first one is *technically* grammatical. There's absolutely no problem with "I will have been working in the cinema industry for 3 months," so swapping working for being ought to be allowed.

However, I don't think a native speaker would ever say that. The second usage of the verb to be is redundant, so people would simply say "I will have been in the cinema industry for 3 months."

I'm afraid I couldn't make much sense of your second example sentence.

Comment: I think it's unusual to use "to be" in continuous forms, because "to be" is normally [stative](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/stative-verbs), implying something which persists for a period of time, so you don't need the continuous. So "we will have been being positive" isn't anything different to "we will have been positive".

Comment: Does the OP mean "We will have _been_ being positive?" If so, the same applies. _being_ is redundant.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable answers